# Problems with Akka Actors to init spark context

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I create an Spark context using scala, this trace is shown:

```
    [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] ERROR akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkDriver-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-5] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkDriver]

    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorkerPool.<init>(Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;I)V
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport.<init>(NettyTransport.scala:283)
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport.<init>(NettyTransport.scala:240)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$2.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:78)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:73)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at akka.remote.EndpointManager$$anonfun$9.apply(Remoting.scala:692)
    at akka.remote.EndpointManager$$anonfun$9.apply(Remoting.scala:684)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:722)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:721)
    at akka.remote.EndpointManager.akka$remote$EndpointManager$$listens(Remoting.scala:684)
    at akka.remote.EndpointManager$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Remoting.scala:492)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at akka.remote.EndpointManager.aroundReceive(Remoting.scala:395)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I read anything about netty version conflict, but I cannot resolve this topic.

This is my set of dependencies:

```
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.2"
    exclude ("com.esotericsoftware.minlog", "minlog")
    exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.transaction")
    exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.mail.glassfish")
    exclude ("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils-core")
    exclude ("commons-digester", "commons-digester")
    exclude ("org.slf4j", "jcl-over-slf4j"),
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.2.2",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-flume" % "1.2.2" exclude ("org.mortbay.jetty", "servlet-api"),
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.2.2",
    "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.2.0" withSources() withJavadoc(),
    "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.2.1" % "test",
    "org.cassandraunit" % "cassandra-unit" % "2.1.3.1" % "test",
    "org.apache.cassandra" % "cassandra-all" % "2.1.3",
    "com.bitmonlab.nrich" % "spark-jobserver-api" % "0.5.0"
)
```

Sorry but I cannot be more verbose because I am totally missing with this topic.

If anything knows what happened with this ...

**UPDATED**

I am just initializing an spark context with cassandra support :

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("QueryExample").setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.cassandr‌​a.connection.host", seeds).set("spark.cassandra.connection.rpc.port", "9171").set("spark.cassandra.connection.native.port","9142") sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
```

Comment: you can at least tell us what you are trying to do! sharing some code samples of what may be causing the error.

Comment: I am just initializing an spark context with cassandra support :


val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("QueryExample").setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", seeds).set("spark.cassandra.connection.rpc.port", "9171").set("spark.cassandra.connection.native.port","9142")
    sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

Comment: you need to update your question with your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a dependency problem. Avro-Tools jar file was being imported to the project and it caused the ERROR. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: how did you solve this...not sure what you mean by avro-tools jar was being imported to the project...thx

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem but using maven instead of sbt. Since i'm including avro-ipc as one of my dependencies, i need to exclude netty, thus, it looked like this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-ipc</artifactId>
    <version>${avro.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```